# Generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for a blob written using a SAS

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

My C# application (using Azure Storage SDK) is writing a blob a partners Azure Storage Account, authentication is via a SAS link they provided.

I'd like to give them an easy download link for the blob by creating a SAS link for it.
This doesn't seem possible as I don't have a sharedKey (only the SAS link)

I've also tried using the querystring from the SAS Link provided by the partner, but that fails auth.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to create a SAS Link after writing the blob using a SAS Link
2. Are there other avenues I should be looking at

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a SAS Link after writing the blob using a SAS
> Link

It is not possible to create a SAS link using another SAS link.

> Are there other avenues I should be looking at

One thing your partner can do is give you a SAS link that has both `write` and `read` permission. That way, they can use the same SAS link to download the blob.

Comment: I have both `read` and `write` permissions, but I'm trying to find a way to give the *partner* an easy download link to the blob I wrote for them - just giving them the Uri of the blob results in an auth issue because public access is not enabled (and they don't want it enabled)

Comment: How does the SAS URL you received look like?

Comment: It has everything enabled...
`https://REDACTED.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2022-10-06T03:21:56Z&st=2022-10-05T19:21:56Z&spr=https&sig=REDACTED`

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation lead me to the fact that if I `write` a blob to a Storage Account that I authenticated to with a SAS link, then the `downloadUri` of that blob contains the SAS link, and is accessible via that.